# Shell script syntax error (if, then, else)

Tags: bash, shell

I have been trying to make a shell script in bash that will display the following:

You are the super user (When I run the script as root).
You are the user: "user" (When I run the script as a user).

```
#!/bin/bash/
if { whoami | grep "root" }; then
echo $USER1
else
echo $USER2
fi
```

I keep recieving these syntax error messages:

```
script.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
script.sh: line 2: `if { whoami | grep "root" }; then'
```

Could someone help me out?

Comment: As Ignacio's answer says, you need to have `;` before the `}`. As the comment on that answer says, you don't need `{` ... `}` at all. And once you get that fixed, you'll probably want to use `grep -q` to hide the output, since all you care about is success or failure. Also, a simple `grep` like this will give you a false positive if your user name is, for example, `notroot`.

Comment: `[ $(id -u) = 0]` is probably the most reliable method. Grepping for the string `root` can give you false positives, and `$USER` can be changed by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 userType="$(whoami)"
 if [ "$userType" = "root" ]; then
    echo "$USER1"
 else
    echo "$USER2"
 fi
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of complication just to prevent checking the result code of `grep`...

Comment: true, don't think you need grep at all

Answer (score 2):

If braces are used to chain commands then the last command **must** have a command separator after it.

```
{ foo ; bar ; }
```

Comment: And note that in this case, the braces aren't necessary: just do `if whoami | grep root; then`....ignoring the more obvious solution using `id` instead of `whoami`

Answer (score 0):

pay attention with your first line, the correct syntax for she-bang is:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

everything you put there, is the interpreter of your script, you can also put something like **`#!/usr/bin/python`** for python scripts, but your question is about the if statement, so you can do this in two ways in shell script using

```
if [ test ] ; then doSomething(); fi
```

or

```
if (( test )) ; then doSomething(); fi
```

so to answer your question basically you need to do this

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ `id -u` -eq 0 ] ; then
        echo "you are root sir";
else
        echo "you are a normal user"
fi

if (( "$USER" = "root" )); then
        echo "you are root sir";
else
        echo "you are a normal user"
fi
```

note that you could use a command using **`` `cmd` ``** or **`$(cmd)`** and compare using `-eq` (equal) or `=` (same), hope this help you :-)

Comment: `if` tests the success or failure of a command. `[ ... ]` is just a special case of that (yes, `[` is actually a command, not part of the shell's syntax, though it's typically a built-in command).  Since the OP specifically wants to test the success or failure of the `whoami | grep "root"` command, there's no need for `[ ... ]` or `(( ... ))`.

Comment: But yes, `if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ] ; then` is probably the cleanest solution. Note that testing `$USER` can be unreliable, since any user can change the value of the `$USER` environment variable.